# What is '<U20' dtype in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i wrote something like this:

```
import numpy as np
n=['28/08/201818:20:35PM']
n=np.array(n)
n
```

the gives me the output `array(['28/08/201818:20:35PM'], dtype='<U20')`
i don't get the dtype in the output.
is it the 'UNICODE' but what about '<' & '20'

Comment: Together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051977/what-is-the-default-dtype-for-str-like-input-in-numpy

Comment: no  that's not what i am asking. That topic shows something else.My question is about a specific dtype of python. BYW i had an answer already & i got what i asked for.Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

A 20-character (`20`) unicode string (`U`) on a little-endian architecture (`<`). [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)